# Loading pre-compiled GStreamer dynamic library for use with Dart FFI fails

Tags: c, flutter, dart, gstreamer, dart-ffi

I'm trying to create a Dart FFI plugin for the [GStreamer](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/) library to use it in my Flutter application on Windows, with plans to expand to other platforms in the future. Since GStreamer is written in C, I thought it would be relatively straightforward to create bindings for it.

To get started, I downloaded the pre-compiled dynamic library from the official website, specifically the `MSVC 64-bit (VS 2019, Release CRT) 1.22.4 runtime installer`. However, I'm having trouble getting the library to load properly.

When I try to run the Dart FFI plugin, I get the following error message:

> Invalid argument(s): Failed to load dynamic library 'gstreamer-1.0-0.dll': error code 126

I've checked that the DLL file is present in the correct directory and I've also added the DLL to my `CMakeLists.txt` file for the plugin.

*Here is Windows `CMakeLists.txt` file:*

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)

set(PROJECT_NAME "gstreamer")
project(${PROJECT_NAME} LANGUAGES CXX)

set(PLUGIN_NAME "gstreamer_plugin")

list(APPEND PLUGIN_SOURCES
  "gstreamer_plugin.cpp"
  "gstreamer_plugin.h"
)

add_library(${PLUGIN_NAME} SHARED
  "include/gstreamer/gstreamer_plugin_c_api.h"
  "gstreamer_plugin_c_api.cpp"
  ${PLUGIN_SOURCES}
)

apply_standard_settings(${PLUGIN_NAME})

set_target_properties(${PLUGIN_NAME} PROPERTIES
  CXX_VISIBILITY_PRESET hidden)
target_compile_definitions(${PLUGIN_NAME} PRIVATE FLUTTER_PLUGIN_IMPL)


target_include_directories(${PLUGIN_NAME} INTERFACE
  "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include")
target_link_libraries(${PLUGIN_NAME} PRIVATE flutter flutter_wrapper_plugin)

# Eveything is Dart's default plugin staff
set(gstreamer_bundled_libraries
  # Only added this line
  "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/gstreamer-1.0-0.dll"
  PARENT_SCOPE
)
```

*Here is my flutter environment setup:*

```
Flutter (Channel stable, 3.10.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.1928], locale en-US)
[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0-rc4)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Community 2022 17.6.4)
[√] Android Studio (version 2022.2)
[√] VS Code (version 1.79.2)
[√] Connected device (3 available)
[√] Network resources
```

What could be causing this issue, and how can I resolve it? Is there anything else I can try to get the dynamic library working properly in my Dart FFI plugin on Windows?

Comment: This just means that one of the other dlls in D:\gstreamer\1.0\msvc_x86_64\bin is required by gstreamer-1.0-0.dll, but windows cannot find it. Make sure that the above bin folder is in your path. (If it is in your path you should be able to type `gst-inspect-1.0.exe` in a command tool and get valid output.)

Comment: I have included `D:\gstreamer\1.0\msvc_x86_64\bin` to `Environment path`. `gst-inspect-1.0.exe` works fine in cmd. But I see no change in the Dart plugin project, the error still exists.

Comment: Create a plain Dart project first and get this to work: `import 'dart:ffi';

void main() {
  final dylib = DynamicLibrary.open(
      'D:\\gstreamer\\1.0\\msvc_x86_64\\bin\\gstreamer-1.0-0.dll');
}`

Comment: I wonder why you are creating any C source of your own. If the dll has a C interface as you state, most of the time you should be able to simply open it and wrap its methods in Dart - i.e. normal Dart ffi.